# "built-in to the library": hyphen or no hyphen

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, writing-style

http://web.mit.edu/galib/www/FeatureList.html says, "You can use the types built-in to the library (bit-string, array, list, tree) or derive a chromosome based on your own objects."

I've sometimes seen "built in to the library".

Should there be a hyphen or not? Should it be "built-in to the library" or "built in to the library"?

Comment: 'You can use the types built into the library ...'

Comment: Perhaps it's using "built-in" as an adjective of some kind? i.e. 'you can use these data structures intrinsic to the library'

Comment: _You can use the types built into the library_ or _You can use the library's built-in types_ - alternative: _You can use the native types of the library_

Comment: Use either "types built **into** the library" or "built-in types **from** the library" both of which should work fine.

Comment: @user3109672 I've never encountered this sort of adjectival usage for built-in. _Intrinsic to_ is a well-known collocation, but not _built-in to_ .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Built-in to" and "Built in to" seem to be used mostly by people talking about computer science. Link: [https://www.google.com/search?q=%22built+in+to+the+library%22](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22built+in+to+the+library%22)

Comment: @user4333994 I'm not so hot on computer science.

Answer (score 2):

Using a hyphen is the wrongest thing to do here. Ideally, the sentence would sound something like this: "You can use the types built into the library". However, if the author meant that the types are somehow built TO the library, which is already grammatically wrong, he should at least have written, "types built in to the library", as a verb and a preposition are complementary.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I see *built-in* as an adjective, whereas *built in* is used as a verb. ie: "the car has *built-in* air conditioning", and "the shelves are *built into* the wall"

Comment: (Downvote not mine) 'built into the wall' is a post-modifying participle phrase. As with many of these, there is ambiguity: it could mean eg 'The next step: the shelves are built into the wall' (more 'verby', addressing the process) or it could mean eg 'In John's flat, the shelves are built into the wall' (adjectival, describing the situation).

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean about how it could either be a verb or adjective, depending on context. Either way, In the example given in the OP, I would not hyphenate the word, and turn it into _built into_

Comment: No, 'it' can't be a verb. Or an adjective. It's a phrase (arguably a clause) – functioning verbally or adjectivally. It's 'a verbal' or 'an adjectival'.

Comment: Oh, I see now, it's not a single word so it can't just be a verb/adjective.

Comment: Not quite the whole story! 'Built into the wall' is certainly not a word / adjective, but in 'the aeroplanes land here, then take off again after refuelling', _land_ is certainly a verb, but it can also be argued that the opposite, _take off_, should also be counted as **a** (multi-word) verb.

Comment: ooohhh, I see, that's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about here is a [compound adjective](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-a-hyphen?page=all). The rules regarding hyphens in compound adjectives are these:

If the compound adjective is right before the noun, use a hyphen:

- Built-in types
- A well-educated student
- The fast-moving river

If the compound adjective directly follows a linking verb, don't use a hyphen:

- The types are built in.
- The student is well educated.
- The river is fast moving.

However, if an adverb in a compound adjective ends in "y," don't use a hyphen regardless of where the compound adjective is:

- A quickly moving river
- The river is quickly moving.
- A finely tuned watch
- My watch is finely tuned.

Then there are some compound adjectives that are always hyphenated.

- A state-of-the-art sound system
- This sound system is state-of-the-art.

**So in your example, you would not use a hyphen: "You can use the types [that are] *built in* to the library."**

Comment: How can this be called an adjective? The postmodifier here is a participle phrase, 'built into the library'. As [Mssrs chompchomp](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) say.